# Japanese text outputs as question marks or goobledy gook

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have worked on this a while, and I tried many of the solutions proffered - to no avail.

In phpadmin the variables are `utf8_unicode_ci`.

A simple query with the following header:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ja" />
```

Outputs question marks:

[image: Gibberish text]

If I add in the line `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`
just before the query I get goobledy gook (mojibake):

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the MySQL **connection encoding** to the same encoding you use on the page. The server converts the results it finds into this encoding, so that you don't have to care about how the data is actually stored.

Since setting the connection UTF-8 produces mojibake your page must have some different encoding. SJIS maybe? Here you'll find the CJK encodings that MySQL supports: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-asian-sets.html

The preferred way to set the ending is with [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php). Executing `SET NAMES` works for encodings that are based on ASCII, like UTF-8, but will not work for others, like sjis. For example:

```
mysql_set_charset('cp932');
```

Also, don't use the `mysql` library in new programs. It has been deprecated and will be removed from PHP at some point.

Comment: Dear Joni,Thank you VERY much. Yes, as you stated I could change the encoding in the browser to UTF-8 & the Japanese data would appear appear correctly, however the HTML Japanese would now be 'mojibake'. Using mysql_set_charset('cp932'); solved the problem.